# Property.ValueChangeListener - Cannot be resolved to a variable (Vaadin)

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm trying the tutorial available on vaadin's website and when I was setting the item selection on a table's row the tutorial suggests that I should add the following line to my table class.

```
addListener((Property.ValueChangeListener), app);
```

Being app a reference to my controller. However eclipse points an error to Property.ValueChangeListener "Property.ValueChangeListener cannot be resolved to a variable".

What exactly am I doing wrong here ?

PS: My believe my imports are correct since eclipse's auto-complete was working just fine to identify .ValueChangeListener

PersonList Class:

```
package com.example.simpleaddressbook2;

import com.vaadin.data.Property;
import com.vaadin.ui.Table;


public class PersonList extends Table {

    public PersonList(Simpleaddressbook2Application app){

        setSizeFull();
        setContainerDataSource(app.getDataSource());
        setVisibleColumns(PersonContainer.NATURAL_COL_ORDER);
        setColumnHeaders(PersonContainer.COL_HEADERS_ENGLISH);
        setSelectable(true);
        setImmediate(true);
        addListener((Property.ValueChangeListener), app);
        setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what was wrong, the correct code is :

```
addListener((Property.ValueChangeListener) app);
```

and not

```
addListener((Property.ValueChangeListener), app);
```

Damn comma !